# Merge two SQL queries

Tags: sql

How to combine two SQL queries in one?

```
SELECT *FROM table1 WHERE chapter=88 AND sentence>=23
SELECT *FROM table1 WHERE chapter=89 AND sentence>=1 AND sentence<=23
```

Comment: Do you want to explain what you expect the merge result to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   TABLE1 
WHERE  ( CHAPTER = 88 
         AND SENTENCE >= 23 ) 
        OR ( CHAPTER = 89 
             AND SENTENCE >= 1 
             AND SENTENCE <= 23 )
```

Comment: @gidil: Please stop editing posts code segments to uppercase. It does not help, makes the code often worse readable than better and it is up to the OP to format the code and if it is not wrong then please leave it as is. If a code block is formatted the OP did it normally the way he likes it and that is fine.

Answer (score 5):

This is one way

```
SELECT *FROM table1 WHERE chapter=88 AND sentence>=23
UNION ALL
SELECT *FROM table1 WHERE chapter=89 AND sentence>=1 AND sentence<=23
```

but you should get into the habit of explicitly listing columns. The columns must align or it won't work.

Here's another way

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
WHERE (chapter=88 AND sentence>=23) OR (chapter=89 AND sentence>=1 AND sentence<=23)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can join the queries like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
WHERE 
(chapter = 88 AND sentence >= 23) 
OR 
(chapter = 89 AND sentence >= 1 AND sentence <= 23)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   TABLE1 
WHERE  ( CHAPTER = 88 
         AND SENTENCE >= 23 ) 
        OR ( CHAPTER = 89 
             AND SENTENCE BETWEEN 1 AND 23 );
```

Answer (score 2):

You've two ways to do it with a table like this and some sample data

```
create table table1 (id number, chapter number, sentence number);

Insert into TABLE1 (ID,CHAPTER,SENTENCE) values (1,65,24);
Insert into TABLE1 (ID,CHAPTER,SENTENCE) values (2,22,22);
Insert into TABLE1 (ID,CHAPTER,SENTENCE) values (3,88,25);
Insert into TABLE1 (ID,CHAPTER,SENTENCE) values (4,89,15);
Insert into TABLE1 (ID,CHAPTER,SENTENCE) values (4,89,33);
```

You can use a union to munge the two sets together

```
SELECT *FROM table1 WHERE chapter=88 AND sentence>=23
UNION
SELECT *FROM table1 WHERE chapter=89 AND sentence>=1 AND sentence<=23;
```

or merge the predicates in the where clause to achieve the same thing

```
SELECT *FROM table1 WHERE (chapter=88 AND sentence>=23) or 
                          (chapter=89 AND sentence>=1 AND sentence<=23);
```

both will give this result

```
|        ID|   CHAPTER|  SENTENCE|
---------------------------------- 
|         3|        88|        25|
|         4|        89|        15|
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE (chapter=88 and sentence>=23) 
OR (chapter=89 and sentence>=1 and sentence<=23)
```

This should return the results from both queries.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table1
 WHERE (chapter = 88 AND sentence >= 23)
    OR (chapter = 89 AND sentence >= 1 AND sentence <= 23)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select *
  From table1
 where ((chapter=88 AND sentence>=23)
     OR (chapter=89 AND sentence>=1 AND sentence<=23));
```

Also, you can use the `BETWEEN` keyword in the second clause.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any Union or Merge statement those operations are redundant. Just change the conditions of your first select.

```
SELECT *FROM table1 WHERE (chapter=88 OR chapter=89) AND 
                    sentence>= (CASE WHEN chapter = 88
                                     THEN 23
                                     WHEN chapter = 89 
                                     THEN 1   
                                 END ) AND
                    sentence <= (CASE WHEN chapter = 89
                                      THEN 23
                                      ELSE sentence
                                  END)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT *FROM table1 WHERE chapter=88 AND sentence>=23
UNION
SELECT *FROM table1 WHERE chapter=89 AND sentence>=1 AND sentence<=23
```